# Email id should be Pre loaded onselect() mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

In my application user will login into his/her account by using his Email ID.
And user will be able to fill the contact details by using drop down.
But in Email ID drop down option it has to be loaded with Email ID which is login Email ID.
Here I am attaching screen shots for better understanding.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
 <label class="control-label">Contact Type</label><br />
 <select class="drop" id="drpContactType" required="required" data-bind="options: ContactTypeList,optionsText: 'Text',optionsValue:'Value',optionsCaption: '--Select--',value:ContactTypeID"></select> </div>
```

When we select EMail ID dropdown option the Email ID which is login by user has to be pre loaded.
can you please help me.

[image]

Comment: You should store login email id in variable after loggedin and once user select email id you should fill textbox with email id

Comment: public JsonResult GetContactTye()
{  using (var entities = new JPortalEntities())
{var ContactTypeList = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize((from m in entities.ContactTypes  where m.IsActive == true
  Select new  {  Text = m.ContactTypeInformation,
  Value = m.ContactTypeID
  }).ToList());
    return Json(ContactTypeList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);            }    }                                                                                                                                         This is wat the code is for get contact type

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Hidden type for Your Email  as I used....You can make hidden field for User Another Details....(like as Email ,Mobile)

```js
$('#cont').change(function () {
  if($(this).val()=='Email')
  {
    $('#val').val($('#email').val());
  }
  else
  {
    $('#val').val('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" value="sandip.viru@gmail.com" id="email">
<div>
  <table>
  <tr>
    <td>Contact type : </td>
    <td>
      <select id="cont">
        <option>Phone</option>
        <option>Email</option>
        <option>Mobile</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>Value : </td>
    <td><input type="text" id="val"></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  
</div>
```

Comment: In my scenario Email is coming from database

Comment: you need to use session for store and retrive email

Comment: $('#drpContactType').change(function () {
        
        if($(this).val()=="ContactTypeID")
        {
            alert('a');
            $('#ContactTypeID').val($('#email').val());
        }
        else
        {
            $('#ContactTypeID').val('');
        }
    });                                                                                                                          trying like this